# Drivelock password option unabled in BIOS for SSD Samsung encryption

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bios, encryption, passwords

I am trying to set a password on my SSD hard disk Samsung 860 EVO in my laptop HP Compaq 6710b. For that I enter to BIOS and the option for Drivelock passwords in the Security menu is unable(gray) and it can´t be setted. This way I can´t encrypt my disk with Samsung Magician with the drivelock method (Class 0). I think that the option for set a hard drive password must be compatible with my BIOS version because the option appears for be abled some way, but perhaps not... Anyone know how can I set this option in the BIOS?. I have owned and activated TPM, and installed HP Protect Tools software with Embedded Security addon.
Thanks.